# Getting started with playn - eclipse

Tags: playn

I followed all the instructions for setting up the environment in eclipse indigo EE. I did it both in ubuntu 12.04 64bit and Windows 7 64bit, and everything goes good till the point when I try to run the imported example (showcase-java). the build fails and following error appears in the eclipse console:

Failed to execute goal on project playn-showcase-java: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-java:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in forplay-legacy (http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo) -> [Help 1]

Note that I follow all the instructions on Getting Started page and I'm sure I'm not missing out on anything mentioned there on the page.

Comment: How are you running the showcase-java sample? "Run as -> Java application" or "Run as -> Maven test"?

Comment: did you install a maven > 3.0.3 or are you using the 3.0.2 integrated in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is a more detailed tutorial on how to set up eclipse with playn [link](http://programmerintrouble.blogspot.de/2013/04/getting-started-with-eclipse-and-playn.html) 
May be this is helpful for you.